# Cypress doesn't work with headless mode on Mac server

Tags: angular, macos, cypress, e2e

When I connect to MAC server using SSH and run `npx cypress run --browser chromium --headless` it throws

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61426/devtools/browser/fac110e3-5a3c-4ed1-9c20-64d59f44f1ec
2023-12-04 09:46:44.707 Cypress[67320:1641419] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:replyErrorCode:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'ClientCallsAuxiliary': Connection interrupted
```

and stuck there forever.
[image]

Meanwhile the same project works just fine on my MacBook.
[image]

I use `cypress@13.6.0` e2e testing with my `Angular@16` project. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, I have moved to `puppeteer`